# How to pass instance primary key from HTML to views.py?

Tags: html, django

I have a table of model instances as following:

```
 _____________________
|1|    |    |    |<a/>|
 _____________________
|2|    |    |    |<a/>|
 _____________________
|3|    |    |    |<a/>|
.......................
 _____________________
```

Django generates it with `for` template loop an the first column is a primary key of model instance. The last column is a link to the page fith form to edit this model instance. I have 2 functions in views.py: to render this page (`edit_employee()`) and to submit changes (`edit_employee_action()`). In the last one I need to process this primary key.

From here user choose instance

```html
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-title" id="number">
                №
            </th>
            <th class="table-title" id="second-name">
                Фамилия
            </th>
            <th class="table-title" id="first-name">
                Имя
            </th>
            <th class="table-title" id="patronymic">
                Отчество
            </th>
            <th class="table-title" id="birth-date">
                Дата рождения
            </th>
        </tr>
        {% for employee in table %}
            <tr>
                {% for field in employee %}
                    <th>{{ field }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
                <th class="button-cell" id="edit"><a employee_id="{{ employee.0 }}" href="{% url 'edit-employee' %}">!</a></th>
                <th class="button-cell negative" id="delete"><a href="{% url 'delete-employee' %}">-</a></th>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Form

```html
  <form id="add-employee-form" action="edit/<int:id>/" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="table-title" id="second-name">
                    Фамилия
                </th>
                <th class="table-title" id="first-name">
                    Имя
                </th>
                <th class="table-title" id="patronymic">
                    Отчество
                </th>
                <th class="table-title" id="birth-date">
                    Дата рождения
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="second-name">
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                        {{ form.second_name.errors }}
                        {{ form.second_name }}
                    </div>
                </th>

                <th id="first-name">
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                        {{ form.first_name.errors }}
                        {{ form.first_name }}
                    </div>
                </th>

                <th id="patronymic">
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                        {{ form.patronymic.errors }}
                        {{ form.patronymic }}
                    </div>
                </th>

                <th id="birth-date">
                    <div class="field-wrapper" id="birth-date-wrapper">
                        {{ form.birth_date.errors }}
                        {{ form.birth_date }}
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
```

urls.py

```py
    path('employee/edit_employee/', views.edit_employee, name='edit-employee'),
    path('employee/edit_employee/edit/', views.edit_employee_action, name='edit-employee-action'),
```

views.py

```py
def edit_employee(request):
    form = AddEmployeeForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'edit_employee.html',
        context={'form': form}
    )

def edit_employee_action(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddEmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            edited_employee = .............
            edited_employee.update(
                first_name = request.POST.first_name,
                second_name = request.POST.second_name,
                patronymic = request.POST.patronymic,
                birth_date = request.POST.birth_date
            )
    else:
        form = AddEmployeeForm()
    form = AddEmployeeForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'edit_employee.html',
        context={'form': form}
    )
```

- How can I pass the primary key from HTML to `views.py`?
- How can I pass this key from `edit_employee()` to `edit_employee_action()`? I could create global variable, but this is not the best way I suppose.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) What Django version are you using? and 2) Are your views function base or class base?

Comment: @JordanM., 2.2.6, function based

Comment: You need to give more detail. Show your actual template, and the URLs and views you want to link to.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `id` parameter in your view's path, in the `urls.py` file:

```py
path('edit_employee_action/<int:id>/', views.edit_employee_action, name='edit_employee_action'),
```

Then add the argument to your `edit_employee_action` view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
# your other imports...

def edit_employee_action(request, id):
    employee = get_object_or_404(YourModel, id=id)  # show a 404 error if the record doesn't exist.
    # the rest of your code
```

Finally add the `id` to your `<a>` tag in the table:

```html
...
<th class="button-cell" id="edit"><a method="post" href="{% url 'edit-employee' employee.id %}">!</a></th>
...
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the final step. You can give it another try now